# Flutter build appbundle , debug-app.apk is working ok but Flutter build apk is not making apk file. What does that mean?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to build apk but firebase admob is making problem I do try to use Flutter build appbundle it make .aab file does that mean I have some AndroidX compatability issue? or something else is wrong?if I run without firebase_admob then apk works perfectly and built without any error how to resolve that issue?
 while app-debug.apk is installing and working fine but I need apk to upload on play store.

I am getting this error :

```
C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1>Flutter build appbundle
Initializing gradle...                                              1.8s
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.6s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             25.5s
Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app.aab (28.3MB).

C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1>Flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           5.5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

  C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:304: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not foun
d.

  C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:305: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.





* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           18.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with your aab file? That is the file you upload to the play store.

Comment: will it work on play store? while I am not able to install directly to my android phone.

Comment: If it produces it without errors then it should do. It is the recommended way to do so.